# Azure Inter-worker process communication

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, azure

I am working to port an application which was designed to work in a non-Azure environment.  One of the elements of the architecture is a singleton which does not scale, and which I'm hoping to replace w/ multiple worker processes serving the resource that the singleton currently provides.

I have the necessary changes in place to replace the singleton, and am at the point of constructing the communications framework to provide interconnection from the UI servers to the resource workers and I'm wondering if I should just use a TCP binding on a WCF service or whether using the Azure Service Bus would make more sense.  The TCP/WCF is easy, but doesn't solve the complete problem:  how do I ensure that only one worker processes a UI request?

From reading the available documentation, it sounds like the service bus will solve this, but I've yet to see a concrete example of implementation.  I'm hoping someone here can assist and/or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that Azure Service Bus **queues** are the right solution for you.

Azure Service Bus can be used in 3 different ways:

- Queues
- Topics
- Relays

From windows azure site:

> Service Bus queues provide one-way asynchronous queuing. A sender sends a message to a Service Bus queue, and a receiver picks up that message at some later time. A queue can have just a single receiver

You can find more info at:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/fundamentals/hybrid-solutions/

Comment: @JohnWollner Here you can find a full example: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-queues/

Comment: @DavideIcardi What if I want to receive a response from the service I am connecting to? For example, If I want to send an email by enqueuing a message to my EmailSender worker role and then receive and answer that the email was sent or not (and the error description).

Comment: @UriAbramson As usual there are many possible solutions. A very simple one is to pass a `messageId` to the worker role. The worker role can use this messageId to write some result information (any storage can be used, like a table storage). Then the client can query that storage using the messageId as a key. For example every 10 seconds the client can check if the message is processed.

Comment: Do you know any push instead of poll based solution?

Comment: @UriAbramson ServiceBus Topics can be used for push style message. You can send a message inside the topic and consumers can create subscriptions for these messages, maybe using a filter to just receive relevant messages. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Davide's answer.

Another alternative would be to use `Windows Azure Queues`. They are designed to facilitate asynchronous communication between web and worker roles. From your web role you push messages into a queue which is polled by your worker roles.

Your worker role can `"Get"` one or more messages from a queue and work on those messages. When you get a message from a queue, you can instruct the queue service to make those messages invisible to other callers for a certain amount of time (known as `message visibility timeout`). That would ensure that only worker role instance get to work on a message.

Once the worker role has completed the work, it can simply delete the message. If there's an error in processing the message, the message automatically reappears in the queue once the visibility timeout period has expired. You may find this link helpful: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/queue-service/.

Comment: Service bus queues provide richer messaging semantics than Azure Queues. See this for a comparison: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh767287.aspx

Comment: I considered a straight up queue, but my understanding is they are limited to an 8K payload which is no nearly enough for my app.

Comment: 8K limit was long time back. Now it is 64K - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179363.aspx.

Comment: Good to know about the limit, although I was at a meetup last month and they were still flogging 8K

Comment: What can I say other than it's a shame that you have been misinformed. On the +ve side, now that you know about the increased limit you have 2 options to choose from if there's a need to be.

Answer (score 1):

Azure queues are not designed for inter process communication, but inter-application communication. The message delivery latency is substantial, and delivery timing cannot be guaranteed. Websockets or NetTcpBinding is more suitable for applications that talk to eachother in realtime. Although must admit, you get some free stuff with queuez, especially the locking mechanisms. Just my 2 cents